# How to gunzip matching files from a directory?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory with a couple of files. I want to gunzip one of them.

Why does

```
ls . | grep "$filter" | gunzip
```

return an error `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format`

while

```
find . -maxdepth=1 -type f -name "*${filter}*" | while read file; do gunzip "$file"; done
```

works just fine?

Comment: The first pipes the filename to `gunzip`’s STDIN, the second gives it as an argument. Why _would_ they do the same? Also, [don’t use `ls` like that](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) .

Comment: The `find` variant would fail on files with linefeeds in their name. Why not simply `for file in *"${filter}"* ; do gunzip "${file}" ; done`?

Comment: Thanks @ruohola. I know it's not meant to be grepped. The question came up in a discussion.

Comment: `gunzip` is not designed to unzip files coming from stdin. Of course, `gunzip $(some_command)`, where `some_command` writes the names of the files to unzip, to stdout, would work. But even this would work only, if none of the filenames contains white space, so I would not recommend it. First focus on how you want to generate the file name list, and then we can think of a reasonable way to do the unzipping,

Answer (score 1):

`ls` lists the file names and you then filter those with `grep` and try to `gunzip` the matching *filenames* as string input.

Changing `| gunzip` to `| xargs gunzip` would correctly operate on the files and not on the filenames ([unless you have spaces in the filenames](https://serverfault.com/questions/516602/how-to-process-a-space-delimited-environment-variable-with-xargs)). But I would not pipe the output of `ls` to anything, it's not meant to be parsed: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs